# I want to delete some outlying parts of multiple models

Tags: python, scripting

I'm curious about a Python script that calls objects one by one from a file and deletes the red part (1mm) of the object as shown in Figure 1 attached below of the object.

Ex) Delete the red part (1mm) of the object as shown in Figure 1.
[image]

Comment: honestly - i have no idea what you mean with the "outer" part? all vertices with all faces which are not inside? or...?

Comment: I edited the post and uploaded it. Please check it.

Comment: i think this would be possible by using a boolean modifier...

Comment: How do I write a script?

Comment: Check the bounding box, create a cube, elongate it along all axes so its dimension are the same as the base object - 2 mm in each axis, then use a boolean modifier set to intersect

Comment: How do I write a script?